# Why is the Scandir() function not working?

Tags: php

I am getting the following php warning when using the scandir() function :

> Scandir failed to open dir: opration not permitted in public_html/page2.php on line 3

page2.php

```
 <?Php
 $folder="/";
 $result=scandir($folder);
 print_r($result);
```

I want to use this function to print the files and sub directories of my root folder but it's not working.

Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: What environment (windows, osx, linux) ?
Do you get any errors?
What is the value of $result?

Comment: What version of php , you are using , can you share.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're trying to scan a directory that you don't have permissions to do (in this case the root directory `/`).

Either change the permissions, or scan a directory you do have permissions for.

This may either be on a directory permissions basis, or using the `open_basedir` directive.

Comment: I have chmoded it to 777 but still the same warning, I think it may be because of my older php version 5.3+

Comment: Check the open_basedir value as well